# Mongo Array in Array Query

Tags: mongodb

Given the below example record, how can I find all users that belong to at least one group from an arbitrary set of groups to query against?   For example, find all users that belong to any one of the following groups - 1, 10, 43.  I'm looking for a generalized solution.  I know I can build out an or query but is there a more efficient way to handle this?

```
> db.users.findOne()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("508f477aca442be537000000"),
    "name" : "Some Name",
    "email" : "some@email.com",
    "groups" : [
        1,5,10
    ]
}
```

Comment: Whats the problem with `$or` query.. its a perfect way to do it..

Comment: There's nothing wrong with it.  It just requires a loop to build the query whereas I can just drop in my array in the method outlined in the answer below without any additional work.  In any case, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`{ groups: {$in: [1, 10, 43]} }`